# Java Caesar Shift Character Print Failure

Tags: java, encryption, character-encoding, caesar-cipher

I am trying to work on a very basic program (that I will later add to) to perform a Caesar Shift on user entered text.

I have a lot of it working, but when I am trying to print out the "encrypted" string, it doesn't work. I am using Netbeans IDE and it just prints out a blank value. I have added in additional print statements to error check and I believe that my "encryption" - i.e. changing the characters, is occurring properly, but when I am recasting it to a character, something fails. My code is below:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package forpractice;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class CaesarShift {

//    public String encrypt(String[] plainText){
//        return null;
//        
//        
//        
//    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // Variable declarations needed for the entire program
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input a string of characters to encrypt: ");
        String plainText = myScan.nextLine();
        String convertedText = plainText.toLowerCase();
        char[] plainTextArray = convertedText.toCharArray();
        ArrayList<Character> encryptedTextArray = new ArrayList<>();
        String encryptedString = new String();


        int currValue;
        char curr;
        char curr1;
        char newCurr;
        int newCurrValue;
        // Variable declarations needed for the entire program

        // Loop through the array, convert to all lowercase, and encrypt it
        for (int i = 0; i < plainTextArray.length; i++){
            curr = plainTextArray[i];
            System.out.println("Current character: " + plainTextArray[i]);
            currValue = (int) curr;
            System.out.println("Current character value: " + currValue);
            newCurrValue = ((currValue-3) % 26);
            System.out.println("Encrypted character value: " + newCurrValue);
            newCurr = (char) newCurrValue;
            System.out.println("Encrypted character: " + newCurr);
            encryptedTextArray.add(newCurr);

        } //end for

        System.out.println("Here is the algorithm :");
        System.out.println("***************");
        System.out.println("Your Plaintext was: " + plainText);

        System.out.println("Your encrypted text was: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < encryptedTextArray.size(); i++){
            encryptedString += encryptedTextArray.get(i);
        }

        System.out.println("***************");


    } //end psvm       
} //end class
```

Any advice or input that you have would be greatly appreciated. I have not found any examples with this specific problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay close attention to the [Ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) table and your expression

```
newCurrValue = ((currValue-3) % 26);
```

You are subtracting 3 from the current value and taking mod 26 after that, which guarantees that you result is within the bounds of 0 to 26. If you look that up in the table you find that there are neither the values for `a` to `z`, nor the values for `A` to `Z`. Actually, all those characters are either invisibe, or blank.

The following example demonstrates the correct use for smallercase characters:

```
newCurrValue = ((currValue - 'a') % 26 - 3); // 3 is your shift value

// if the result is negative, simply add 26 (amount of smallercase characters)
if (newCurrValue < 0) {
    newCurrValue += 26;
}
newCurrValue += 'a'; // add 'a' again, to be within 'a' - 'z'
```

Also, despite your little error, you wouldnt have seen the result on the console anyways, as you were missing a  log statement:

```
System.out.println("Your encrypted text was: ");
for (int i = 0; i < encryptedTextArray.size(); i++) {
    encryptedString += encryptedTextArray.get(i);
}
System.out.println(encryptedString); // output your result
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. You were definitely correct and it was an oversight on my part.